# Find the second largest score in a team and return name

Tags: excel

Using excel how can I lookup a team in column 1, find the second largest score for that team and return the name from the second column. Without using VBA.

```
Teams   Name    Score
team 1  Jill    4.0%
team 1  Bill    68.0%
team 1  Lill    1.0%
team 2  Bob     55.0%
team 2  Dot     71.0%
team 2  Rob     44.0%
team 3  Anna    71.0%
team 3  Elle    74.0%
team 3  Ada     19.0%
```

So for the given table the answers would be

[image: answers]

This is my current attempt. Trying to find a match in teams and return that dereferenced result as an array offset to the score column. Where H1 references "team 1".

```
{=LARGE(OFFSET(N(IF(1,IF(H1=A1:A9,H1))),,2),2)}
```

Comment: Read about pivot tables.

Comment: Been asked on here - golfing was recent...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen       pivot tables wont do. I need just the result in a specified cell. Not manually lookup using filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your provided data a solution could look like this **ARRAY FORMULA: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(LARGE((C2:C10)*(A2:A10=F2),F3),(C2:C10)*(A2:A10=F2),0))
```

Be aware though, that this just finds the first occurance of the ranked score in the chosen team. So if Anna and Ada of team 3 both have the same score just Anna will be shown as result. You could add another column to count number of occurances of this specific score in the team.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10=F2)*(C2:C10=LARGE((C2:C10)*(A2:A10=F2),F3)))
```

[image]